# Why print() is printing my String as an optional?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a dictionary and I want to use some of its values as a key for another dictionary:

```
let key: String = String(dictionary["anotherKey"])
```

here, `dictionary["anotherKey"]` is `42` but when I print `key` in the debugger I see the following:

```
(lldb) expression print(key)
Optional(42)
```

How is that possible? To my understanding, the `String()` constructor does **not** return an optional (and the compiler **does not complain** when I write `let key: String` instead of `let key: String?`). Can someone explain what's going on here?

As a sidenote, I am currently solving this using the `description()` method.

Comment: Remember people, adding a comment with the reason for downvoting always helps.

Comment: I also added some playground code for reference [here](https://gist.github.com/phi161/2aa87e2df26f66f7146a7e6cff22c0cb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design - it is how Swift's `Dictionary` is implemented:

> Swift’s `Dictionary` type implements its key-value subscripting as a subscript that takes and returns an optional type. [...] The `Dictionary` type uses an optional subscript type to model the fact that not every key will have a value, and to give a way to delete a value for a key by assigning a nil value for that key. ([link to documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html))

You can unwrap the result in an `if let` construct to get rid of optional, like this:

```
if let val = dictionary["anotherKey"] {
    ... // Here, val is not optional
}
```

If you are certain that the value is there, for example, because you put it into the dictionary a few steps before, you could force unwrapping with the `!` operator as well:

```
let key: String = String(dictionary["anotherKey"]!)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you doublecheck your last line? I think you meant `let key: String = String(dictionary["anotherKey"]!)` (pay attention to the `!`)

Comment: @phi Ah, of course, the exclamation point needs to be inside. That's what happens when I try answering questions in a language that is still relatively new to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding the result. The `String` initializer does not return an optional. It returns the string representation of an optional. It is an non-optional String with value `"Optional(42)"`.

Answer (score 1):

**A Swift dictionary always return an Optional.**

`dictionary["anotherKey"]` gives `Optional(42)`, so `String(dictionary["anotherKey"])` gives `"Optional(42)"` exactly as expected (because the Optional type conforms to StringLiteralConvertible, so you get a String representation of the Optional).

You have to unwrap, with `if let` for example.

```
if let key = dictionary["anotherKey"] {
    // use `key` here  
}
```

This is when the compiler already knows the type of the dictionary value.

If not, for example if the type is AnyObject, you can use `as? String`:

```
if let key = dictionary["anotherKey"] as? String {
    // use `key` here  
}
```

or as an Int if the AnyObject is actually an Int:

```
if let key = dictionary["anotherKey"] as? Int {
    // use `key` here  
}
```

or use `Int()` to convert the string number into an integer:

```
if let stringKey = dictionary["anotherKey"], intKey = Int(stringKey) {
    // use `intKey` here  
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think you mean `as? Int` instead, right? Now it makes sense, I had to unwrap the Int, not the String.

Comment: But in my scenario, my type is `AnyObject` and I want to cast an `Int` to a `String` (not the opposite). Thus, I used your snippet that does `as? String` but it won't work since it cannot unwrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid force unwrapping by using default for the case that there is no such key in dictionary

```
var dictionary = ["anotherkey" : 42]

let key: String = 
String(dictionary["anotherkey", default: 0])
print(key)
```